# How can I change mapping for vim-surround plugin?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-vim-surround

I don't mind keeping the original mapping, I just want to bind it to something more convenient, so instead of typing <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>)</kbd>, I could for example do it with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>(</kbd>.

I tried just adding `nnoremap <M-(> ysiw)` to my `.vimrc`, but that did nothing.

I use gVim 8,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by grodzik, `nnoremap` does not take any non-standard mappings into account. That includes mappings by plugins. Simply changing to `nmap` is not the right way to go in my opinion. You will start to get used to `Alt (` and not need `ysiw)` anymore. With an `nmap` you will never be able to map something else to `ysiw)` (or `ys`) because that will break the `Alt (` mapping.

I think you should map directly to the `vim-surround` commands. In this case that would be

```
nnoremap <M-(> :execute "normal \<Plug>Ysurroundiw)"<cr>
```

This calls `<Plug>Ysurround` which is usually done using `ys` and then does the `iw)` part. Other commands can be found in the `surround.vim` file that is part of the `vim-surround` plugin.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to use `nmap`, not `nnoremap`, since `s` is already a mapping from `Surround` plugin. `nmap` scans right side for further mappings - see `:h :nmap`.

As of notation `<M-(>` - I'm not sure if it's correct. I would do it as follows (and I actually tested it like so) - while editing your `.vimrc` in gVim in place of `<M-(>` press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> and then your combination <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> - this will insert actual key code. It should look like so:

```
nmap ¹ ysiw)
```